# object won't animate if number animation properties are defined elsewhere in qml

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, qml

I don't know if what im trying to do is possible, although it seems to me like it should be... Im trying to animate an object using sequential or parallel animation. This works fine if the number animation properties are set normally within itself (as the documentation suggests), but i do not want to hardcode the number animation object to a single setting/object, i would prefer the sequential animation to be top level thus accessing the number animation object (within the sequential animation) from elsewhere... Interestingly, when i have made the desired settings, the console output on the number animation object shows everything is set, but still no animation. Here's what i got so far:

```
   Component.onCompleted: {
    anim.accessToNum.target = rect
    anim.accessToNum.property = "x"
    anim.accessToNum.to = 100
    anim.accessToNum.duration = 1000
}

Rectangle {
    id: rect
    width: 50; height: 50
    color: "red"
}
SequentialAnimation {
    id: anim
    running: true
    property var accessToNum: num
    NumberAnimation { id: num}
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
    running: true
```

set on the animation, so it immediately begins animating with no `target`, `property`, etc.

Do this instead:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    width: 600
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Component.onCompleted: {
        anim.accessToNum.target = rect
        anim.accessToNum.property = "x"
        anim.accessToNum.to = 100
        anim.accessToNum.duration = 1000
        anim.start() // or: anim.running = true
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        width: 50
        height: 50
        color: "red"
    }
    SequentialAnimation {
        id: anim
        property var accessToNum: num
        NumberAnimation {
            id: num
        }
    }
}
```

Unrelated tip: use `alias` instead of `var`, when possible; it's slightly cheaper:

```
property alias accessToNum: num
```

Comment: Wow that worked and thanks alot for your quick response! I had in my code example previously added the anim.start(), but whilst the running:true property was declared. You have spared me pain! Lol all the best Mitch.